# Understand the circuit LED

Tags: circuit-analysis, led, circuit-design, led-strip, led-matrix

Help me to understand the circuit

If I power up this circuit, what will happen? Will the LEDs glow or will they be damaged?

[LED datasheet link -EAHC2835WD6](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/EAHC2835WD6/6002463)

**LED Lighting - White, Cool 6500K 3.1V 150mA 120° 1411 (3528 Metric)**

[image: Circuit]

Provide some guidelines to design the LED matrix.

Comment: Can you tell us what value the resistors are?

Comment: But looking at the LED specs they will drop 12.4V so won’t output any significant light whatever the resistor values are.  You probably want strings of 3 LEDs which will drop 9.3V and then choose a resistor that allows no more than 150mA to flow when (12-9.3)V is applied, so about 18 ohms.  You could start with 22 ohms and then put 100 ohms in parallel if you need  to go to the max output.  You’ll need at least 0.5W resistors.

Comment: 50ohm, 0.5W resistor placed at end.

Comment: that is a sensible value, but you’ll need to drop from 4 LEDs to 3 in each string

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate your circuit?

Comment: How will you cool the LEDs? The specs in the datasheet are when the solder points are cooled to 25 degrees C somehow. Where can you buy LEDs with 3.1V typical forward voltage? They can be from 2.8V to 3.4V.

Comment: No, @winny , is there any way, please suggest me.

Comment: Indeed. LTspice and ngspce are free. Falstad does not require any installation. EE 101 is to simulate your circuit to understand it.

Comment: that would work and last a very long time, even without a resistor, but since the voltage of the source can vary, a 5-10 ohm resistor is a good safety measure. You won't get full luminosity out of the LEDs as they need 3.1 to pull 150ma, so at only 3.0v they will likely pull about 100ma. If that's suitable, then go for it, it's a great way to run things efficiently and cool.

Answer (score 1):

In the [datasheet](https://everlightamericas.com/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=2355), Fig.4 (Forward Current vs. Forward Voltage), the curve is roughly linear, so we can approximately model the LED as a series of a constant-voltage source of 2.5V (zero-current point) in series with a 4.5-Ohm resistor (curve slope).

So, each of the two branches translates to a 10V constant-voltage source in series with 18+50R resistance. Connected to a 12V source, this results in a computed current of (12V - 10V)/(18R + 50R) = 30mA, just one fifth of the nominal current (150mA).

BUT: Current-vs-Voltage curves of LEDs vary between individual samples, with temperature, aging and so on. So, the circuit shown plays it very safe, and even with all the possible variations it will surely stay well below the absolute maximum ratings, but also far below the maximum brightness.

Fig.2 (Relative Luminous Intensity vs. Forward Current) shows us another plausible reason for the small current value: the luminous intensity does not grow linearly with current, so choosing a smaller current gives a better efficiency: with a fifth of the nominal current, you get a quarter of the nominal light, meaning a 25% increase in efficiency.

So, if you want maximum luminous intensity out of a given number of LEDs, go for high current, but make sure to respect the absolute maximum (in case of this LED, 180mA).

If you want maximum efficiency (at the cost of using more LEDs), go for low current, as does the circuit you showed us.